# Android - Horizontal listview inside Listview row

Tags: android, listview, horizontallist

facing problem while creating horizontal listview inside listview custom row. Problem is that, first row of listview is having 3 items i.e. A, B C. and second row of listview , having 6 items in horizontal list view i.e. A,B,C, D,E,F.

I am not able to get out of this problem.

[image]

Here is code snippets

Creating 3 arraylist

```
List<SectionArea> sectionAreas;
List<BannerArea> bannerAreas;
List<Wrapper> wrappers;
```

Code to fetch json data from server

```
 wrappers = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();
                            // Code to get all wrapper in Icons list
                            JSONArray wrapperArray = object.getJSONArray("wrapper");
                            for (int i = 0; i < wrapperArray.length(); i++) {

                                sectionAreas = new ArrayList<SectionArea>();
                                bannerAreas = new ArrayList<BannerArea>();

                                JSONObject wrapperObj = wrapperArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String section_image = wrapperObj.getString("section_image");
                                String category_id = wrapperObj.getString("category_id");
                                String category_name = wrapperObj.getString("category_name");
                                String banner_title = wrapperObj.getString("banner_title");

                                JSONArray sectioArray = wrapperObj.getJSONArray("sectionarea");
                                for (int j = 0; j < sectioArray.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = sectioArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String product_id = jsonObject.getString("product_id");
                                    String sec_category_id = jsonObject.getString("category_id");
                                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                                    String price = jsonObject.getString("price");
                                    String special = jsonObject.getString("special");
                                    String discount = jsonObject.getString("discount");

                                    SectionArea sectionArea = new SectionArea(product_id, sec_category_id, name, image, price, special, discount);
                                    sectionAreas.add(sectionArea);

                                }

                                JSONArray bannerAreaArray = wrapperObj.getJSONArray("bannerarea");
                                for (int k = 0; k < bannerAreaArray.length(); k++) {


                                    JSONObject jsonObject = bannerAreaArray.getJSONObject(k);
                                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                                    String tag = jsonObject.getString("tag");
                                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");

                                    BannerArea bannerArea = new BannerArea(image, tag, id);
                                    bannerAreas.add(bannerArea);
                                }

                                Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(section_image, category_id, category_name, banner_title,
                                        sectionAreas, bannerAreas);
                                wrappers.add(wrapper);

                            }

                        }
```

Adding adapter

```
 list.setAdapter(new HomePageAdapter(context, wrappers));
```

Adapter code for setting Horizontal list view

```
 sectionAreas = wrappers.get(position).getSectionAreas();
        viewHolder.item_list.setAdapter(new HorizontaListAdapter(mContext, sectionAreas));
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what issues you are getting..?

Comment: @MeenalSharma - Issue is that second row of listview's horizontal listview have 3+3 items in it. Means 3 from 1st row and 3 form 2nd row.

Comment: Are you clearing the list before adding the items for second view? I prefer using two different lists for two different listviews

Comment: I am using 2 different list - sectionarea and bannerarea to merged in on wrapper list.

Comment: Share your HomePageAdapter class.

Comment: Here is HomePageAdapter - https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/7c40358a30534cab973fbbe425dc4e93

Comment: @Beena - here is whole project - https://github.com/Sanwal13/DoomsDay

Comment: @Piyush - Same problem with recyclerview too

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `LinearlayoutManager` with `RecyclerView`.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line from your `HomePageAdapter` class

```
   viewHolder.item_list.setAdapter(new HorizontaListAdapter(mContext, sectionAreas));
```

With

```
  viewHolder.item_list.setAdapter(new HorizontaListAdapter(mContext, wrappers.get(position).getSectionAreas()));
```

Also replace following lines from your code of class `MainActivity`

```
          sectionAreas = new ArrayList<SectionArea>();
          bannerAreas = new ArrayList<BannerArea>();
```

by

```
    ArrayList<SectionArea>  sectionAreas = new ArrayList<SectionArea>();
    ArrayList<BannerArea>  bannerAreas = new ArrayList<BannerArea>();
```

And remove public variable

```
List<SectionArea> sectionAreas;
List<BannerArea> bannerAreas;
```

**NOTES :**

I have checked you code and find that you have used `HorizontalView` to display items horizontally.
So just a suggestion, Instead of using any custom class you can use Android default Horizontal `RecyclerView`. Which is more reliable.

EX of usage:

```
  RecyclerView recyclerTeams= (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTeams);
  LinearLayoutManager llManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
  recyclerTeams.setLayoutManager(llManager);
```

Comment: @MarkLoke : Not able to test  ur app as it display one loader initially. And nothing happens. Can you please provide flow so that i can check it?

Comment: I have changed HorizontalView to RecyclerView but same error. Repeating data in rows.